# Make table notes as wide as `\textwidth` while preserving table's own width

Tags: tables, width, threeparttable, tablenotes, textwidth

I use the `threeparttable` package to make tables, for the following reasons:

- It allows me to conveniently make table notes that may refer to specific text in the table;
- The table notes are tightly spaced.

For some reason, I need to make the table notes as wide as the surrounding text (`\textwidth`) while keeping the table its original, natural width. I have not been able to do this since in `threeparttable` the table are as wide as the table notes. In the MWE, I had to make the table as wide as the surrounding text to make the table notes as wide.

**How do I make the table notes as wide as the surrounding text `\textwidth` while still keeping the table its natural width** and while retaining the two nice features of the `threeparttable` package describe above?

MWE:

[image: table notes MWE]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \footnotesize
        \caption{A Narrow Table}
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \sisetup{
                detect-mode,
                tight-spacing            = true,
                group-digits             = false,
                input-signs              = ,
                input-symbols            = ,
                input-open-uncertainty   = ,
                input-close-uncertainty  = ,
                table-align-text-pre     = false,
                round-mode               = figures,
                round-precision          = 3,
                %       round-integer-to-decimal = true,
                table-space-text-pre     = (,
                table-space-text-post    = ),
            }
            \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l*{1}{S}}
                \toprule
                Estimator          & {My Guess}            \\
                \cmidrule{2-2}
                Dependent variable & {Lottery Result}      \\
                \midrule
                Treatment          & 53.7667               \\
                                   & (3.1877)              \\
                Constant           & 86.2173***            \\
                                   & (3.4262)              \\
                \addlinespace
                Observations       & {3578}                \\
                \midrule
                Test: 0 = 2        & {$p=0.1576$}\tnote{a} \\
                Test: 1 = 3        & {$p=0.9706$}\tnote{a} \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular*}
            \begin{tablenotes}
                \item A note that does not reference anything. Significance is
                    denoted: * $p < 0.10$  ** $p < 0.05$  *** $p < 0.01$.
                \item[a] A note that references text in the table.
            \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}

Surrounding text: \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that you have to redefine some internal macro of the package: add

```
\makeatletter
\let\TPT@hookin\@gobble
\let\TPT@hookarg\@gobble
\makeatother
```

before `\begin{document}`.

[image: PDF.png]

EDIT: Complete code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\let\TPT@hookin\@gobble
\let\TPT@hookarg\@gobble
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \footnotesize
        \caption{A Narrow Table}
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \sisetup{
                detect-mode,
                tight-spacing            = true,
                group-digits             = false,
                input-signs              = ,
                input-symbols            = ,
                input-open-uncertainty   = ,
                input-close-uncertainty  = ,
                table-align-text-pre     = false,
                round-mode               = figures,
                round-precision          = 3,
                %       round-integer-to-decimal = true,
                table-space-text-pre     = (,
                table-space-text-post    = ),
            }
            \begin{tabular}{lS}
                \toprule
                Estimator          & {My Guess}            \\
                \cmidrule{2-2}
                Dependent variable & {Lottery Result}      \\
                \midrule
                Treatment          & 53.7667               \\
                                   & (3.1877)              \\
                Constant           & 86.2173***            \\
                                   & (3.4262)              \\
                \addlinespace
                Observations       & {3578}                \\
                \midrule
                Test: 0 = 2        & {$p=0.1576$}\tnote{a} \\
                Test: 1 = 3        & {$p=0.9706$}\tnote{a} \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tablenotes}
                \item A note that does not reference anything. Significance is
                    denoted: * $p < 0.10$  ** $p < 0.05$  *** $p < 0.01$.
                \item[a] A note that references text in the table.
            \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}

Surrounding text: \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I added the macro but am not seeing the result in your screenshot. Could you please include the complete code?